# sync the same code blocks file across multiple computers

Tags: c++, synchronization

i have began coding on a separate computer from my home one and i am running code blocks off of a USB, but i have come across a problem when moving back to my home PC to use the same project. the problem is with syncing the files that have been updated on my USB back to my computer doing it manually is beginning to take longer and longer as the amount of files in my my project increases.

so my question is, is there some way  (in code blocks preferably but if there is another ide that does it then i guess i will use that) to sync an old project with a new one and have it overwrites all the old code?

Comment: I use bitbucket.com for this, but there's also github.com. Git and Mercurial would of course work on a USB-stick too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a version control system. Git would be a good choice, since you can set up a bare repository on the USB stick and sync with it from each machine.

Git has a hefty learning curve, but the huge benefits to your workflow will be worth the effort many times over.

Another choice is Mercurial. I strongly dislike Mercurial's branching model(s) (which I consider to be broken) and the lack of a staging area, but many projects have had good success with it, so it's worth considering. Mercurial also has the advantages of being easier to learn and better supported on Windows than git.